# IgGrid: How to get the odata queryString of remote filtering in JavaScript

Tags: odata, uri, filtering, ignite-ui, iggrid

I use infragistics grid (v16.1) with remote filtering.
When I filter column "Name" I see that the grid makes GET request in the following manner:

```
http://SERVER/grid/GetAll?&%24filter=indexof(tolower(name)%2C%27iv%27)+ge+0&page=0&pageSize=30&pk=id&_=1473841534609&pageSize=30&pk=id&_=1473841534609
```

The part between "filter=" and "&page" `indexof(tolower(name)%2C%27iv%27)+ge+0` is query option of OData Uri components that I am interested in.

I need to use this request URI or only the query option in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the url parameters using the `_encodeUrl()` method of the grid’s data source, for example:

```
var encodedUrl = $("#grid").data("igGrid").dataSource._encodeUrl()
```

This will return an object with all of the current url parameters that would be send if a remote request is initiated.